# Inheritance from CGAL::Polyhedron_3

Tags: c++, inheritance, cgal

I inherited from a CGAL::polyhedron_3 an Enriched_polyhedron and add some extra functions then I started to get problems when using  boost graph interface however it runs very well with CGAL::polyhedron_3 
Error
no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘struct boost::property_traits’

I am trying to add boost namespace like this but it didn't help

```
namespace boost
{
template <class K, class I>
struct graph_traits<Enriched_polyhedron<K, I>> : public graph_traits<CGAL::Polyhedron_3<K, I>>
{
};
} // namespace boost
namespace boost
{
template <class K, class I, class Tag, class enabled>
struct property_map<Enriched_polyhedron<K, I>, Tag,enabled> : public property_map<CGAL::Polyhedron_3<K, I>, Tag,enabled>
{
};

template <class kernel, class items>
class Enriched_polyhedron : public CGAL::Polyhedron_3<kernel, items>
{
....... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow what is done for `Surface_mesh` in the following [example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/Surface_mesh_2sm_derivation_8cpp-example.html).

Comment: I followed  the example but I got an error: ‘graph_has_property’ is not a class template

Comment: In the CGAL namespace? You also probably need to include `boost/graph/properties.h` (but it should be already included by Polyhedron).

Comment: also, I tried to compile the mentioned surface mesh example and it gives the same error

Comment: the weird thing that the surface mesh example also generate the same error when I tried to build it

Comment: What version of CGAL are you using? (in old release maybe removing the partial specialization of graph_has_property might be sufficient)

Comment: std::cout << "My CGAL library is " <<  CGAL_VERSION_NR                              
My CGAL library is 1041101000

Comment: I installed CGAL using sudo apt-get install libcgal-dev

Comment: My CGAL library is 1041101000 (1MMmmb1000)

where MM is the major number release, mm is the minor number release, and b is the bug fixing number release.

Comment: Did you try removing the specialization from your code?

Comment: How Could I Do That?

Comment: remove the struct/class `graph_has_property` from your code.